# can not find "sql development tools" in eclipse marketplace

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate

I want to install "SQL development tools" in eclipse, as i am learning Hibernate(from a tutorial video), but i can not find it in the marketplace. does anyone know, if the name changed or any alternative for this "SQL development tools".

Comment: I recommend using https://dbeaver.io/

Comment: What tutorial video?

Comment: one of udemy courses.

Comment: It sounds like the Udemy course is asking you to install dev tools generically, meaning for whatever database you're using. At any rate, you're going to have to be more descriptive -- you can't expect people to know the content of that Udemy course.